# Java tron Collision,Combobox

Tags: java, arraylist, combobox, collision

I'm trying to do my school project "Tron". I'm newbie when it comes to programming... I did some collisions with arraylist and they are working fine.But I can't do collision snake with other object ... I'm using this:
snake1x and snake1y are coordinates of first snake and obstacleX is arraylist that contains coordinates of other object.

```
for(int l=0;l<obstacleX.size();l++) {
if((snake1x == obstacleX.get(l)) && (snake1y == obstacleY.get(l))) {
running = false;
}
}
```

I have the object already drawn in my game but snake will just pass throught it ... :(
the weird thing is that I did this with similiar method on collision between snakes and it works fine :)

My second problem is with combobox and choosing a color for snake..

```
if (snake1 = true) {
 for (int p = 0; p < pathx1.size(); p++) {
  g.setColor(Color.white);
   g.fillRect(pathx1.get(p), pathy1.get(p), width, height);
```

I could simply give it colour like this but I need to choose it from the combobox
and that where I am lost :)

I will appreciate any help or anything that could improve my work like adding other things and something like that thanks~~ :-)

Comment: What is the datatype of snake1x and snake1y? If they are objects you might want to consider using "equals" method to compare the objects. == tests whether they reference the SAME object. I think this might be the problem.

Comment: they are integers only holding the coordinates and then they are added to arraylists - and so the "tron" is created thats how i make the trail

Comment: I still think you are experiencing a problem of "autoboxing" and comparing different objects with "==" operator. Without looking at how obstacleX ArrayList is populated and how snake1x is declared and assigned, it's difficult to get you a precise answer to solve your first problem. I have created an answer with a test program to show you the result which may be surprising. But hopefully it'll help you to explain the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class AutoBoxingTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        Integer intObj = 1;
        ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<>();
        intArray.add(new Integer(1)); // Forcefully create a new Integer object
        intArray.add(1);

        if(i==intArray.get(0))
            System.out.println("Equals");
        else 
            System.out.println("Not Equals");

        if(intObj==intArray.get(0))
            System.out.println("Equals");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Equals");

        if(intObj==intArray.get(1))
            System.out.println("Equals");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Equals");
    }
}
```

When you run this program, you get the result

```
Equals
Not Equals
Equals
```

Notice the difference between intArray.get(0) and intArray.get(1). Even though both are 1, they are different objects.